# Can't Customize Wordpress Page

Tags: customization, theme-customizer

[image: click customize]

When I click to customize my page, I get the spinny wheel.
I've tried restoring to previous days on my site, but am having no luck. Thank you for your help.

[image: infinite spinning wheel]

Comment: I resolved this issue by deactivating my Plugins. I then was able to customize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several way to fix this problem

1. Clear your browser cache
2. Deactivate all plugins and reactive step by
   step
3. Change php versions